# Differences between "suck up" and "suck in"

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs

I am not sure if we can use both phrasal verb to mean the same thing. I am thinking of using them as "swallow" or "gulp down". Is that semantically correct?

For example:

> The black hole sucked up the entire solar system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Suck up" is used for drinks, especially when drunk through a straw. It is also used figuratively to mean "put up with a difficult situation"

"Suck in" can be used, for example for pulling in your belly to appear slimmer. It could also be used for sucking in air for example into a jet.

Scientifically neither is a good description of a black hole, which is a gravity field, and doesn't suck anything.  It would be better to say "The whole solar system fell into the black hole".